# Automating DXF drawings based on dimensions from Excel

Tags: automation, autocad, cad, dxf

I am currently using Solid Edge as a means to create flat pattern dxf drawings of sheet metal parts for plasma/laser cutting. I would like to automate parts, that require very simplistic flat patterns, but take time to model manually, because of the bulk sizes.

A simple part is a rectangle with 2 open ends, the open end has a width and a height, and the rectangle itself has a depth. An example would be a 250x400 opening, with the sides length being 500.

This would result in a 650x500 part. (Counting extra for a neutral factor of bending length based on material thickness, for example a 4mm thick part would be 651.2, with a bend centerline of 250.6).

Now I would need to automate creating a DXF with a 651.2x500 rectangle, based on the given 250x400 opening and 500 depth.
Any ideas?

I have tried Solid Edge API Automation, but the process seems too complicated for simply creating DXF files. I don't think this extra weight in automating a 3d part creation, 2d flat patterning and then saving as DXF is worth it. I'm hoping to cut the middle-man (design software) and cut straight to autocad DXF.

Comment: Would you have a drawing of the geometry of the part you wish to create?